# Fancyhdr suddenly not working in a big project

Tags: fancyhdr, books

I'm writing an open-source maths book, and as the project is pretty far in the working, I don't think I can really show a MWE. My issue is that `fancyhdr` doesn't work, i.e. I see no headers, footers, etc. - including the page numbers. It used to work in the past, but I just noticed the issue, so it could be there for some time now.

This are the (probably) relevant files:

1. [Makefile](https://github.com/pelegs/maths_book/blob/main/Makefile).
2. [Main settings](https://github.com/pelegs/maths_book/blob/main/settings.tex).
3. [Main compiled file](https://github.com/pelegs/maths_book/blob/main/bookmain.tex).

Are there any known packages/settings that clash with `fancyhdr`? I'm pretty lost here unfortunately...

Comment: what about moving back in your github commits and find the place where the headers vanished or at least a commit where it still works? then comapre the settings between then and now.

Comment: You have a `\pagestyle{empty}` in `cover.tex`. This applies to the rest of the book. So add a `\pagestyle{fancy}` at the end of that file (after the `\newpage`) or maybe use `\thispagestyle{empty}` instead.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: the problem is that there are many, many commits - and each time I would have to compile some part and check... I could have done that, but I assumed someone here would be more familiar with the causes for such an issue, so they'll suggest simple corrections. And apparently, I was right :)
If I had gone through the commits I would still not know the issue, because `cover.tex` was created in a single commit.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum: awesome, that was exactly the problem. Many thanks!